# Smallest natural deduction proof for Meredith's axiom from basic rules

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, alternative-proof, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I tried to find a *small* natural deduction proof for Meredith's single axiom

| Infix notation | Polish notation |
| --- | --- |
| [((((ψ→φ)→(¬χ→¬ξ))→χ)→τ)→((τ→ψ)→(ξ→ψ))](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((((a%E2%86%92b)%E2%86%92(%C2%ACc%E2%86%92%C2%ACd))%E2%86%92c)%E2%86%92e)%E2%86%92((e%E2%86%92a)%E2%86%92(d%E2%86%92a))) | `CCCCCpqCNrNsrtCCtpCsp` |

but I failed. My proof (shown below) has a whooping **72 steps**. Am I missing something? Can it be reduced further, or are natural deduction proofs just that big over only basic rules? For example, the semantic tableau proof (linked above) is much smaller.

So, essentially, I am looking for three things:

1. A smaller proof for Meredith's single axiom.
2. Methods to find optimal proofs in natural deduction systems.
3. Ways to show that such a given proof is optimal.

#### Inference Rules

I'm looking for the smallest possible natural deduction proof, based **only** on the rules of {¬,→,∨,∧,↔}-{elimination,introduction} and ⊥-introduction, i.e. *no* derived rules:

[image]

#### My Attempt

The proof can be imported into https://mrieppel.github.io/fitchjs/ for automated validation and a prettier view.

```
Problem:  |- (((((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) > E) > ((E > A) > (D > A)))

1   |_  ((((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) > E)                          Assumption
2   | |_  (E > A)                                                  Assumption
3   | | |_  D                                                      Assumption
4   | | | |_  ~(~(((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) v E)                  Assumption
5   | | | | |_  E                                                  Assumption
6   | | | | |   (~(((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) v E)                 5  vI
7   | | | | |   #                                                  4,6  #I
8   | | | |   ~E                                                   5-7  ~I
9   | | | | |_  ~(((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C)                       Assumption
10  | | | | |   (~(((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) v E)                 9  vI
11  | | | | |   #                                                  4,10  #I
12  | | | |   ~~(((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C)                        9-11  ~I
13  | | | |   (((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C)                          12  ~E
14  | | | |   E                                                    1,13  >E
15  | | | |   #                                                    8,14  #I
16  | | |   ~~(~(((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) v E)                   4-15  ~I
17  | | |   (~(((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) v E)                     16  ~E
18  | | | |_  ~(((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C)                         Assumption
19  | | | | |_  ~((A > B) > (~C > ~D))                             Assumption
20  | | | | | |_  ((A > B) > (~C > ~D))                            Assumption
21  | | | | | | |_  ~C                                             Assumption
22  | | | | | | |   #                                              19,20  #I
23  | | | | | |   ~~C                                              21-22  ~I
24  | | | | | |   C                                                23  ~E
25  | | | | |   (((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C)                        20-24  >I
26  | | | | |   #                                                  18,25  #I
27  | | | |   ~~((A > B) > (~C > ~D))                              19-26  ~I
28  | | | |   ((A > B) > (~C > ~D))                                27  ~E
29  | | | | |_  C                                                  Assumption
30  | | | | | |_  ((A > B) > (~C > ~D))                            Assumption
31  | | | | | |   C                                                29  Reit
32  | | | | |   (((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C)                        30-31  >I
33  | | | | |   #                                                  18,32  #I
34  | | | |   ~C                                                   29-33  ~I
35  | | | | |_  ~(~(A > B) v (~C > ~D))                            Assumption
36  | | | | | |_  ~(A > B)                                         Assumption
37  | | | | | |   (~(A > B) v (~C > ~D))                           36  vI
38  | | | | | |   #                                                35,37  #I
39  | | | | |   ~~(A > B)                                          36-38  ~I
40  | | | | |   (A > B)                                            39  ~E
41  | | | | | |_  (~C > ~D)                                        Assumption
42  | | | | | |   (~(A > B) v (~C > ~D))                           41  vI
43  | | | | | |   #                                                35,42  #I
44  | | | | |   ~(~C > ~D)                                         41-43  ~I
45  | | | | |   (~C > ~D)                                          28,40  >E
46  | | | | |   #                                                  44,45  #I
47  | | | |   ~~(~(A > B) v (~C > ~D))                             35-46  ~I
48  | | | |   (~(A > B) v (~C > ~D))                               47  ~E
49  | | | | |_  ~(A > B)                                           Assumption
50  | | | | | |_  ~A                                               Assumption
51  | | | | | | |_  A                                              Assumption
52  | | | | | | | |_  ~B                                           Assumption
53  | | | | | | | |   #                                            50,51  #I
54  | | | | | | |   ~~B                                            52-53  ~I
55  | | | | | | |   B                                              54  ~E
56  | | | | | |   (A > B)                                          51-55  >I
57  | | | | | |   #                                                49,56  #I
58  | | | | |   ~~A                                                50-57  ~I
59  | | | | |   A                                                  58  ~E
60  | | | | |_  (~C > ~D)                                          Assumption
61  | | | | |   ~D                                                 60,34  >E
62  | | | | | |_  ~A                                               Assumption
63  | | | | | |   #                                                3,61  #I
64  | | | | |   ~~A                                                62-63  ~I
65  | | | | |   A                                                  64  ~E
66  | | | |   A                                                    48,49-59,60-65  vE
67  | | | |_  E                                                    Assumption
68  | | | |   A                                                    2,67  >E
69  | | |   A                                                      17,18-66,67-68  vE
70  | |   (D > A)                                                  3-69  >I
71  |   ((E > A) > (D > A))                                        2-70  >I
72    (((((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) > E) > ((E > A) > (D > A)))    1-71  >I
```

#### Proofs in Answers

For proofs in answers that do not provide a method for machine-based validation, this section is meant to provide plain text variants compatible with the [fitchjs](https://github.com/mrieppel/fitchjs) project.

- [Bram28](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4881217)'s proof (26 steps)

  ```
  Problem:  |- (((((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) > E) > ((E > A) > (D > A)))

  1   |_  ((((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) > E)                          Assumption
  2   | |_  (E > A)                                                  Assumption
  3   | | |_  D                                                      Assumption
  4   | | | |_  ~A                                                   Assumption
  5   | | | | |_  A                                                  Assumption
  6   | | | | | |_  ~B                                               Assumption
  7   | | | | | |   #                                                4,5  #I
  8   | | | | |   ~~B                                                6-7  ~I
  9   | | | | |   B                                                  8  ~E
  10  | | | |   (A > B)                                              5-9  >I
  11  | | | | |_  ((A > B) > (~C > ~D))                              Assumption
  12  | | | | |   (~C > ~D)                                          11,10  >E
  13  | | | | | |_  ~C                                               Assumption
  14  | | | | | |   ~D                                               12,13  >E
  15  | | | | | |   #                                                3,14  #I
  16  | | | | |   ~~C                                                13-15  ~I
  17  | | | | |   C                                                  16  ~E
  18  | | | |   (((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C)                          11-17  >I
  19  | | | |   E                                                    1,18  >E
  20  | | | |   A                                                    2,19  >E
  21  | | | |   #                                                    4,20  #I
  22  | | |   ~~A                                                    4-21  ~I
  23  | | |   A                                                      22  ~E
  24  | |   (D > A)                                                  3-23  >I
  25  |   ((E > A) > (D > A))                                        2-24  >I
  26    (((((A > B) > (~C > ~D)) > C) > E) > ((E > A) > (D > A)))    1-25  >I
  ```

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but you could make it a bit clearer. Are you asking for a method to find optimal proofs in a natural deduction system? Or a way of showing that a given proof that you have already found is optimal? Or what?  (My initial reaction is that I am unsurprised that semantic tableaux - which in a sense do a lot of things in parallel - can give a much compact proof than a system with no parallelism like natural deduction.)

Comment: @RobArthan Both, and I am also looking for a smaller proof. I edited the question.

Comment: @RobArthan Seems it turned out that this natural deduction system can just do as a semantic tableau, I just failed to see how, due to total inexperience initially with this kind of proof. Compressing the 3⋅4 steps for *ex falso quodlibet* into 3⋅2 steps would already arrive at 20 steps (like in the tableau).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 26 line proof (if you don't count line 1):

[image]

Comment: Nice! How did you find it? Do you have any strategic insights / suggestions?

Comment: @xamid It’s all pretty straightforward really. The goal obviously suggests a triple nested conditional proof, and I note you did exactly that as well. So then the goal became $A$, and for proving atomic statements a proof by contradiction strategy can be very useful … and I also noted the $A \to B$ which can readily be obtained once you have $\neg A$, so that was further confirmation that I should get the $A$ using proof by contradiction. And indeed, after that the rest just fell into place.

Comment: @xamid The statement to prove contained only negations and conditionals as connectives.  That suggests the most elegant syntactic proof would be built around the inference rules for those; which do not indicate making assumptions involving disjunctions.

Comment: Your strategy of using proofs by cases isn’t very efficient here since you don’t have any disjunctions to start with and you had to prove the disjunctions in the first place. In a case like this, where all you have are conditionals and negations use conditional proofs and proofs by contradiction… and that should always work: the rules involving conditional, negation and contradiction are complete to prove any statement involving just conditionals and negations.

Comment: Tanks again, I hope keeping these things in mind will help me to find better proofs in the future. I still wonder if there is no research about minimization of such proofs.. PS: I tried twice to edit in a plaintext version for easy automated validation of your proof, but got rejected twice. Will now put it in the question instead.

Comment: @xamid I am pretty sure some people are looking for 'minimal proofs' .. though typically that would involve proofs where there are a small number of rules or axioms ... like the very Meredith system! I haven't seen proofs that prove that some formal natural deduction -style proof is minimal.  Pretty sure my proof is minimal though :P  Also, I used a software program called Fitch for my proof, which checks for validity of all the steps ... as you can see, all steps checked out in Fitch. If you want a proof in your format that's up to you.

Comment: I know this kind of research is done for Hilbert systems like Meredith's system, I am conducting it myself. Natural deduction to me seemed more like a concept useful to teach basic concepts in manual proof writing rather than in proof theoretic research, but I tried to challenge my impression. Regarding your final point, it is not about a specific format, but about the option for readers to easily verify a formal proof via automated deduction *themselves*. This would not only have added value to your answer – enabling automated validation is the whole point of formal proofs.